# How to say "truck driver" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

What do you call a truck driver in German? It is a man who drives a truck.

What does LKW-Fahrer, the term I've been taught, mean in this context?

Comment: it ma ydepend on where you need the word. if it is a jobdescription or translation of a novel... what do you need?

Comment: Yiddish had a nice term for this occupation in the old country: "balagulah" (= ba'al ha-agulah, Heb. "master of the wheels"). Generally a horse-and-wagon driver but i think it would have carried over to a motorized freight driver.

Answer (score 14):

This is to long for a comment. Ad Infinitums answer is already very good.

But actually the most common word in colloquial language is *LKW- Fahrer* as mentioned in the question itself.

LKW- Fahrer is simply a short form for **L**ast**k**raft**w**agen- Fahrer, who is -you guess- the Fahrer of a Lastkraftwagen. A short -and still valid- form ist *Lastwagenfahrer* as mentioned by Martin.

A *Fernfahrer* is mostly the same but with the connotation of driving long distances, whereas an LKW- Fahrer could also drive the refuse lorry.

The third suggestion *Berufskraftfahrer* is an umbrella term for everybody driving a *Kraftfahrzeug* in his job, that can be a taxi, bus, truck or even a car of a pizza delivery service.

As Perl Dog mentions in his comment, there is an even more colloquial term: *Brummifahrer* is used in colloquial speech. It is an onomatopoeia and describes the sound of a truck or more general a car: "Brumm" or even "Brumm-Brumm" is, what already very small children will say, if you point to a truck (or any other car) and ask, what it is.

Comment: Very good summary for all these related words.

Comment: To my experience _Brummifahrer_ is even more colloquial.

Comment: For persons who don't come home in the evening. Instead doing long travels and sleep in their vehicles is "Fernfahrer" the most common expression in everyday German.

Answer (score 4):

You can just say *Lastwagenfahrer*.

Remark: It does not necessarily have to be long-distance which *Fernfahrer* would imply.

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia suggests **Fernfahrer**.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernfahrer

P.S

I would like to mention my method to find the best suggestion(s). It works most of the time for me.

For example, if I am looking for a specific word but the dictionary suggests me lots of words (sometimes very irrelevant words) and when I am not sure, which one to pick. In these cases, I follow the following steps;

**1**.Search the target word in Wikipedia (English)

**2**.Scroll down a little

**3**.Click on the Deutsch on the left side under languages section

**4**.You have the word in German(This works naturally for other languages as well)

I am also not native speaker of German and for your question, I found the word in this way. Lets see what the native speakers will say.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I also like this method of translation.

Comment: @äüö I am happy to see my method works good:) With this method, I can find very specific words. E.g the name of flowers, animals etc..

Comment: Note that "Fernfahrer" has a connotation that "LKW-Fahrer" doesn't have. Both drive a truck, but the former term indicates that you drive over a long distance, the latter one just states that you drive a truck.

Comment: And note the term [Berufskraftfahrer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berufskraftfahrer) which includes truck driver.

Comment: @Ad Infinitum: this method is a good one very often, but sometimes it is very misleading one.. because the naming of articles on Wikipedia isn't really perfect everytime..

Comment: @Em1 could a driver, who drives a "PKW", over a long distance be called as well Fernfahrer?

Comment: @AdInfinitum "Fernfahrer" is associated with truck drivers.

Comment: @cornejo Yes, Wikipedia is never a reliable source. However, it can be used at least to find your direction.

Comment: @Em1 then, it can be said that "Fernfahrer" is a subset of "Berufskraftfahrer"

Comment: @AdInfinitum Yes, but note that Berufskraftfahrer also includes bus drivers, for instance. It's not a good fit for a translation of truck driver, I just wanted to point out that there's another term which occasionally comes up. — Btw, the best translation imho is just "LKW-Fahrer". ;)

Comment: @Em1 Then, please feel free to edit my answer:)

Comment: Berufskraftfahrer is anyone who drives a "Kraftfahrzeug" in his job. This can be taxi drivers, bus drivers, truck drivers as "Kraftfahrzeug" is not restricted to trucks, but means (almost) everything that uses fuel to drive...